# What does "held an edge" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "It's an environment like nothing I've ever seen," said Democratic nominee Gretchen Whitmer, a former legislative leader, who has **held an edge** in state public opinion surveys.

I think "**held an edge**" here means "**had an edge**". The last part is saying that *the former legislative leader took the lead in state public opinion surveys*.

But I'm not quite sure if my understanding is correct because I've never seen the phrase "**hold an edge**".

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/governors-races-trump-emerges-defining-issue-141442965--election.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **hold** means "to maintain" or "to remain constant (in something) over time".

An **edge** in the context of opinion surveys refers to a marginal lead versus the opposing candidate(s).

So she has maintained a marginal lead in those opinion surveys. She has been leading by a narrow margin.

To **take the lead** in the context of an opinion survey means to move from a second or lower position into the top position.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of related idiomatic expressions:

> To **edge out / edge in**
>
> To have **an edge on**
>
> A **knife-edge** (margin, lead, profit, etc.)

In this context the meaning is that the democrat has a *slight* lead in the polls, metaphorically as thin as the *edge* of the blade of a knife.

Written differently, it could imply she managed to work her way into the lead through some gap in her opponent's electorate or strategy.

> The Democratic nominee **edged out** her opponent in the polls with a message that appealed to the core values of the party.

Metaphorically this is like taking a knife or some similar thin object, and using it to *wedge open* something.